# Specialize Class for all other types

Tags: c++, templates

Assume having `MyContainer` template class, like:

```
template <typename T>
class MyContainer {
public:
    T *content;
    void *data;
};
```

Now, assume having `MyContetWithData` class as well, which already contains the `void *data` field, hence there is no need to duplicate it in `MyContainer`, **but**, all other types yet need said field, only `MyContetWithData` does not need it.

How can we specialize `MyContainer` so that `void *data;` is removed from `MyContainer` if `T` is of type `MyContetWithData`, but keep said field for all other types?

Comment: What's wrong with adding the specialization you mention, i.e. `template <> class MyContainer<MyContetWithData> { MyContetWithData *content; };` ?

Comment: I didn't mention such specialization, only the word "specialize".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply provide an [explicit specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) for `MyContetWithData` as shown below:

```
//primary template for all other types as before
template <typename T>
class MyContainer {
public:
    T *content;
    void *data;
};
//explicit specialization for MyContetWithData without data
template <> class MyContainer<MyContetWithData> 
{ 
    MyContetWithData *content;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dqEjbs7hG)

Comment: Some old compilers may fail if the "`template <>`" part is on the same line as `class`, but is acceptable.